# Visa validity period before entering the US from Nigeria

Tags: visas

I am from Nigeria but in Haiti at the moment. I got a two year US visa in 2017 here in Haiti and have traveled severally to Nigeria with it. I intend to travel to Nigeria in Dec.,to return to Haiti 1st week of January through the US. My visa will expire on 16th of February 2019. Will i be allowed to pass through US on my return with the visa? I intend to renew it on my arrival in Haiti in February 2019 or do you suggest i renew before travelling?

Comment: If your visa is valid, you can use it.